# Custom Dialog not getting display over incoming call screen in Samsung Galaxy A5

Tags: android, service, dialog, flags, android-windowmanager

My code is working fine in most of the devices but not in samsung galaxy A5 
I am trying to display my custom overlay dialog over the native dialer , so that by clicking on it I can redirect user to my application.**i have tested my code in Smasung J7 prime , Samsung onNXT , Moto G4 plus etc** in every device **it's working fine** , **don't know that why it's not working on Samsung Galaxy A5**

Does anyone over here face the same ?

**Here is my code** :-

```
private static WindowManager wm;
public static View popupView;
private static WindowManager.LayoutParams params1;

private static void showPopup(Context applicationContext) {
    wm = (WindowManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    params1 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    params1.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params1.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params1.x = 0;
    params1.y = 0;
    params1.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    params1.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) applicationContext
                    .getSystemService(applicationContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, null);
    int[] attrs = new int[]{R.attr.selectableItemBackground};
    TypedArray typedArray = applicationContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    int backgroundResource = typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0);
    popupView.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource);
    wm.addView(popupView, params1);
    popupView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    popupView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            startActivity(applicationContext);
        }
    });
}
```

**Xml for PopUp view** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rv_parentview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_bg">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_size_very_small">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_size_very_small"
                android:text="Add Call"
                style="@style/FontHeavyBold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_size_very_small"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text_size_very_small">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/fill_circle_bg" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/white_add_call" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- <TextView
                 style="@style/FontHeavyBold"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:paddingLeft="90dp"
                 android:paddingRight="90dp"
                 android:text="Add Call"
                 android:textAppearance="@style/FontLight"
                 android:textColor="@color/app_color"
                 android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

             <ImageView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_size_very_small"
                 android:src="@mipmap/ico_return" />-->

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post a complete function? You use global vars now.

Comment: @greenapps , Please have a look on my updated question , i posted my whole service

Comment: That is not what i asked for. I will not mess around with your sevice. I asked for a complete `showPopup()` function which i can call in an onClick() event. You should make it easy for us to help you. I just want to copy/paste one function.

Comment: Please check above now ..is that fine , i pasted my xml code , variables and full function , now you just need to call this function and put your static images and dimensions in code ,if it's still not as per your expectation ,let me know

Answer (score 1):

Add this permission check to your onCreate()

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Check if the application has draw over other apps permission or not?
    //This permission is by default available for API<23. But for API > 23
    //you have to ask for the permission in runtime.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&   !Settings.canDrawOverlays(getActivity())) {
        //If the draw over permission is not available open the settings screen
        //to grant the permission.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getActivity().getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION);
    }

}
```

And add onActivityResult()

```
private static final int CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION = 2084;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION) {

        //Check if the permission is granted or not.
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        }
        else
            {
                // Permission is not available
            }

    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Use AlertDialog and change the window type to TYPE_PHONE

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context.getApplicationContext());
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.caller_dialog, null);
            Window window = alert.getWindow();
            builder.setView(dialogView);
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            window.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE);
            alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            alert.show();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
            lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
            //This makes the dialog take up the full width
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            window.setAttributes(lp);
```

Don't forget to add this permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
```

Comment: Overlay permission is already coming on A5 but my dialog not appearing on native dialer Ui when screen is locked

Comment: Did you try changing the type to 'WindowManager.LayoutParams.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE);' ?

Comment: yes , i tried to add this line in code but it's saying can not resolve setType (i think this will work with Window window = getWindow();)